# How to access S3 bucket using IAM roles in NODEJS project

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to get rid of hard coded credentials and use IAM roles to access S3 buckets in my NodeJS project. Any lead or suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the details on the official AWS website https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-access-s3-bucket/

After this you should have access to s3 directly from the ec2 instance with keys.